# How to Mock BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE

Tags: android, mocking, android-activity, mockito, robotium

I'm trying to solve a problem with a the following code which i have got to test:
I'm using Mockito and Robotium to solve the most testcases.
The problem is to mock an answer from the user by a request dialog started through:

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, BluetoothAdapterService.REQ_BT_ENABLE);
```

The answer is cached by

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     

    if (requestCode == 1) {                                                             /*TODO: für 1 eine Konstante verwenden, hier und in der aufrufenden Funktion*/
        if (resultCode ==   BluetoothAdapterService.REQ_BT_ENABLE) {                    /*TODO RequestCode == ResultCode dh. der COde kann hier optimiert werden*/
            btAdapterService.setBluetoothState(BluetoothAdapterService.ON);
        }
        else {
            btAdapterService.setBluetoothState(BluetoothAdapterService.OFF);            /* Wenn keine Verbindung aufgebaut werden konnte, oder die Aktivierungsaufforderung des -> */                                                                           /* BT-Adapters mit nein quittiert wurde, ist der resultCode = RESULT_CANCELD = 0 */
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried some solutions to get the button clicked which shows up during the test but although Iam using robotium I cant acces the button by

```
solo.clickOnText("No");
```

Is it also possible to paste the request into another class and call a method for it? So that i could reuse the request in diffrent ways? I tried this out but then i got the problem that no request shows up and i get an exception.

I'm not an indeep programmer and i have started know with this topic. I would appreciate every help.

Comment: What are you going to do with Bluetooth adapter?

Comment: Depending on the Bluetooth- State the user gets the above listed User- Dialog to activate BT. It's started by the intent. When i get this dialog i want to be able to select on or off through the callback-function. Maybe there is a easier way with Robotium but till now i havent found out to get this special dialog and his buttons.

Comment: so are you just going to turn on/off Bluetooth?

Comment: Yeah through a Intent which is requested. The code for turn of the bluetooph adapter is known. I dont understand how to react on the user dialog which is given by the BluetoothAdapter himself (API talks about system activity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is purpose of your tests. As for me it sounds like you want to be sure that your code processes user's answer correctly.

So for me it would be enough just to call `onActivityResult(1,BluetoothAdapterService.REQ_BT_ENABLE)` and check after that bluetooth was enabled.

Comment: Just to execute _onActivityResult(1,BluetoothAdapterService.REQ_BT_ENABLE)_
don't solve the problem because **onActivityResult** is unknown in the test context. So maybe you mean 
**mActivity.onActivityResult(1, 1, new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));**

but to use this i need to remove the protected declaration and then it still doesnt work.

Comment: Sure you can make public function which will call protected method. But this is already a lot just for test class. I was writing answer in approach how to do that with unit tests. I don't have much experience with instrumental tests

Comment: Ok. I can also try it under unit test. I will give a report asap.

Comment: Ok the unit test could be the solution. I can call the callback by

Comment: _mActivity.onActivityResult(1, 1, new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));_ This is an acceptable solution. Thanks a lot.